# mono_crash hidden files in home directory

Tags: crash, hidden-files

I have noticed that there are some hidden files in my home directory (Ubuntu 20.04) with names like 'mono_crash.d4716fb0.0.json' and 'mono_crash.mem.4398.1.blob'

There was 2 of the json files and 3 of the blob files

My guess is that they are a crash report which seems to be supported by when I googled, however I couldn't find much information.

I think they may be from when I first installed ubuntu and my broken touchscreen was causing issues which I have now disabled.

Should they be stored in my home directory?
I do not have regular crashes, and the system seems to be working fine, can I now delete these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem on removing them.

They were created by some application developed with [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)). When the application crashes, it dumps the memory content into those `.blob` files. Take a look at your `.json` file and you might find which application to blame. I also happened to find in my home folder some of them and they were created by `gnome-subtitles`. Check it out:

```
$ grep thread_name mono_crash.c0a5b8e87.0.json
"thread_name" : "gnome-subtitles",
```